# How to convert black and white QR code to string of ones and zeros?

Tags: python, qr-code

I've used the [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) library to generate a QR code. Now I would like to derive a string of ones and zeros from it, such that black pixels are `1`, white pixels are `0`, and I make one long string of all the rows concatenated together with line breaks.

In other words, it would look like figure 4 below. How would I generate this?

[image]

Here is the code to generate the QR code:

```
import qrcode
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=10,
    border=4,
)
data = "hello world!"
qr.add_data(data)
qr.make(fit=True)

img = qr.make_image(back_color=(255, 255, 255), fill_color=(0, 0, 0))

img.save("test.png")
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [print_ascii](https://morioh.com/p/8ab487b39f96)?

Comment: What string are you referring to? Please make concrete example.

Comment: @alec_djinn Black represents 1, white represents 0, get the string shown in circle 4 (picture in question)

Comment: So you want one continuous string that concatenates all the rows of ones and zeros?

Comment: @teapot418 Thanks for the idea, I'm trying to figure out how to convert ASCII characters into 0 and 1

Answer (score 2):

By trying the workaround I got, but not elegant

```
import qrcode

# Set the colors corresponding to 0 and 1 respectively, the default is black and white
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=None, box_size=1, border=0,
                   error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L)

# The string to generate (can be any text)
data = "Hello, world!"

# Add the data of the QR code to be generated to the qr object
qr.add_data(data)

# Generate a QR code and save it as a PNG file
img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
img.save("qr_code.png")

# Convert QR code data to 01 string
qr_str = qr.get_matrix()
qr_str = '\n'.join([''.join([('1' if cell else '0') for cell in row]) for row in qr_str])
print(qr_str)
```

[image]

Comment: Some line breaks would make that `join` list comprehension a lot more readable, but other than that this looks fine to me. Not inelegant at all, assuming you really do (for whatever reason) actually need this output format.

Comment: @CrazyChucky:Yes, after I get the string, I will use other codes to generate an artistic QR code, similar to the image below.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/miH7J.png

Comment: In that case you can probably just use the matrix directly rather than generating a string based on it.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: Sorry, I am new to programming, I may not have the corresponding programming logic, and I have not learned enough. For now, it is enough to have a way to achieve it, of course, I hope there is a better way to achieve it.